# Subscribe users to my twitter account

Tags: twitter

I have some problem with twitter integration in my website. 
You can see some information below:

I created Twitter app in my account and users authorize my app. Can I automatically subscribe these users to me? I tried to read Twitter API but I didn't find solution for my problem.

Could you help me?

Comment: To help me understand, are you trying to get a user to automatically follow you when they open your app?

Comment: Hello! Yes, you a right!

Comment: I'm not sure if that is even doable. I have never followed someone automatically after downloading an app or visiting a website. Plus, I am not sure you want to that, it will annoy a lot of users and you will just get bad ratings in the App stores.